# Processing paths like /search/:search(/filter1/:filter1)?

Tags: node.js, rest, express, chaining, restify

I'd like to be able to process paths like this ones

```
/search/:search
/search/:search/filter1/:filter1
/search/:search/filter2/:filter2
/search/:search/filter1/:filter1/filter2/:filter2
```

How should I do that using restify or expressjs (or any other REST lib)?

I know I can create a handler based on regular expressions, and then parse arguments and call manually handlers for each part, but I intuit that there should be some easier and more structural way of chaining handlers using methods of the library. Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks.

---

**[EDIT]**
My view of the pervect solution would be something similar to this:

```
REST.get('/search/:search(/filter1/:filter1)?(/filter2/:filter2)?',function(req,res,next){
    // handler for search where $search is always defined, 
    // but $filter1 and $filter2 are optional
});
```

**By now solved like this until better solution found**

---

If there will be no better propositions, by now I'm doing it like this:

```
var searchHandler = function (req,res,next){};
REST.get('/search/:search', searchHandler);
REST.get('/search/:search/filter1/:filter1', searchHandler);
REST.get('/search/:search/filter2/:filter2', searchHandler);
REST.get('/search/:search/filter1/:filter1/filter2/:filter2', searchHandler);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off thinking of 'search' as the resource and all those filters as query parameters. In other words, do something like this instead:

```
REST.get('/search',function(req,res,next){
    var filter1 = req.params.filter1;

    if(filter1 !== undefined){
        // Do something with it here.
    }

    // Etc.
});
```

And your URL would look something like this:

```
http://localhost/search?filter1=green
```

Comment: I know I could do that, but just wished to make it nicer, like friendly urls :) Anyway thanks.